# how can I fix binary files a and b differ error in this program?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, diff, binaryfiles

this is program for file transfer server and client

Both server and client code I ran normally. However, when I used the diff command to compare the original file and the transmitted file, only the words 'binary files test.txt and receivefile.txt differ' were output. I know you can compare binary files using cmp, but I have to use diff. How do I change the code so I can compare the two with the diff command?

server code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define BUFFSIZE 4096
#define SERVERPORT 7799

int main(void){
    int s_sock, c_sock;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr, client_addr;
    socklen_t c_addr_size;
    char buf[BUFFSIZE] = {0};
    char filename[BUFFSIZE] = {0};

    int read_len;
    int newfile;
    int writefile;
    int fileread_len;



    s_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    bzero(&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));

    int option = 1;
    setsockopt(s_sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &option, sizeof(option));
    // already in use error

    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(SERVERPORT);
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    if(bind(s_sock, (struct sockaddr *) &server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) == -1){
        perror("bind error");
        exit(1);
    }

    listen(s_sock,1);

    c_addr_size = sizeof(struct sockaddr);
    c_sock = accept(s_sock, (struct sockaddr *) &client_addr, &c_addr_size);
    if(c_sock == -1){
        perror("accept error");
        exit(1);
    }

   
    read_len = read(c_sock, buf, BUFFSIZE);
    if(read_len > 0){
        strcpy(filename,buf);
    }else{
        close(c_sock);
        printf("file len error");
    }

    newfile = open(filename, O_RDONLY);
    if(!newfile){
        perror("there is no file for open");
        exit(1);
    }

    while((fileread_len=read(newfile, buf, BUFFSIZE)) != 0){
        writefile = write(c_sock, buf, BUFFSIZE);
    }
    close(c_sock);
    close(newfile);
    close(s_sock);
    return 0;
}
```

client code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define BUFFSIZE 4096
#define SERVERPORT 7799

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    if(argc != 4){
        printf("<Usage : ./hw11c IP PORT FILENAME >\n");
    }

    int c_sock;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr, client_addr;
    socklen_t c_addr_size;
    char buf[BUFFSIZE] = {0};
    char filename[BUFFSIZE] = {0};
    int receivefile;
    int filenamelen;
    int recv_len;

    c_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    bzero(&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));

    int option = 1;
    setsockopt(c_sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &option, sizeof(option));
    // already in use 

    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[2]));
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[1]);

    strcpy(filename,argv[3]);

    filenamelen = strlen(filename);

    if(connect(c_sock,(struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) == -1){
        perror("connect error");
        exit(1);
    }

    send(c_sock, filename, filenamelen, 0);

    receivefile = open("receivefile.txt", O_CREAT | O_EXCL | O_WRONLY ,0700);
    // receivefile = open(filename, O_CREAT | O_EXCL | O_RDWR); 
    if(!receivefile){
        perror("there is no receive file");
        exit(1);
    }

    while((recv_len = recv(c_sock, buf, BUFFSIZE, 0)) != 0)
    {
        write(receivefile, buf, recv_len);
    }

    close(receivefile);
    close(c_sock);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: 'read_len = read(c_sock, buf, BUFFSIZE);
    if(read_len > 0){
        strcpy(filename,buf);'   There are no messages longer than one byte in TCP.  Your assumption that the whole filename, nothing less,  nothing more, will be loaded with only one recv() call is false and dangerous.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. But does it have anything to do with this error? I'm asking because I really don't know.

Comment: Who knows?  Same failure to correctly and completely handle the results returned from system calls applies to send(), recv() throughout your code:(

Comment: How about this for an idea - do some debugging/logging.  How about printing out recv_len so you can check up how many bytes were received?

Comment: Wait, what's this?  ' while((fileread_len=read(newfile, buf, BUFFSIZE)) != 0){
        writefile = write(c_sock, buf, BUFFSIZE);' ???  You read 'fileread_len' in one line, then write BUFFSIZE bytes to the socket?    Why would you do that?

Comment: .. and I got there by thinking about debugging, first by suggesting you print out client received bytes, then I looked at the server send code to suggest printing out sent bytes and.....

Comment: In the client's while loop printf("%d\n",recv_len); I tried putting it, but 4096 comes out. Something weird... is it? The test.txt content is only abcdefg.

//
If while((fileread_len=read(newfile, buf, BUFFSIZE)) != 0) is the problem, how can I fix it?

Comment: while(1){
        fileread_len=read(newfile, buf, BUFFSIZE);
        writefile = write(c_sock, buf, BUFFSIZE);
        if(fileread_len == EOF | fileread_len == 0){
            break;
        }
    }                 fix code.. but still error

Comment: You see, developing software has very little to do with writing code.  Organizing data is more important.  Testing, debugging and logging is where it's at.

Comment: EOF..............what?   You are going backwards.  Get rid of the EOF check.  Log both ends - how many bytes are sent in total, how many bytes are received in total.  Find out which end has the problem. Cut problems in half until you find the error.

Comment: I tried referring to other socket codes on the internet, is it still wrong? If something is wrong, please let me know how to fix it

Comment: I also printed the writefile, but it is the same as 4096.

Comment: Aarrghhh!     Again, 'fileread_len=read(newfile, buf, BUFFSIZE); ' reads fileread_len bytes.  'writefile = write(c_sock, buf, BUFFSIZE)' writes BUFFSIZE bytes.  Stop writing more than you read!

Comment: I mean, you got it right in the client!  You write exactly as many bytes as you receive.  Just do the same in the server.

Comment: oh i got it! thank you so much.. really.. 'writefile = write(c_sock, buf, fileread_len);' after fix that, all work correctly

Comment: `perror("there is no file for open");` leads to very confusing error messages along the lines of "there is no file for open: permission denied".  Instead, just do `perror(filename)`.